# Create a new Entry in Kafka Schema Registry using a file (Curl)

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

The 'simple' syntax for adding an entry in Schema registry goes this way :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" --data '{"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Payment\",\"namespace\":\"io.confluent.examples.clients.basicavro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"double\"}]}"}' http://localhost:8081/subjects/test-value/versions
```

However, when doing it from terminal, if the schema is large, this can be pretty heavy and unpractical. Is there a convenient way not to blot the curl command with the inline schema (i.e the schema content), and just pass an avro schema file (avsc) ?

I know there is a [python tool](https://gist.github.com/aseigneurin/5730c07b4136a84acb5aeec42310312c) that does that :

```
$ python register_schema.py http://localhost:8081 persons-avro person.avsc
```

I am also aware I can do it (with much boilerplate code) in Java via http requests

But I was wondering if there was a way to do it right from the command line (without python, in plain bash)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do this with `jq` and the `tojson` function.

To load `/tmp/example.avsc` schema to `my_schema_01-value` subject run:

```sh
jq '. | {schema: tojson}' /tmp/example.avsc  | \
    curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/subjects/my_schema_01-value/versions \
         -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
         -d @-
```

Ref: https://rmoff.net/2019/01/17/confluent-schema-registry-rest-api-cheatsheet/

Comment: Sweet. didn't know about jq. works nicely. Although I was ideally looking for a way to avoid the use of extra libs since this will be done a production server. But it does the job pretty well